# Usando el método .splice( ) en Javascript, se elimina el elemento de un array, pero al hacerlo, no se muestran adecuadamente los elementos restantes

Tags: javascript, array, funciones, function, eliminar

En este código se ocupa el método .splice( ) para eliminar un elemento del array y cuando eso sucede, una vez que se quiere mostrar cuantos elementos quedan, se descontrola la manera en que se visualizan los elementos restantes.

Al final del código está la función que contiene a dicho método y se encarga de eliminar los elementos según el número de id.

No sé si tal vez estaré accesando de manera inadecuada a la posición del elemento pero en realidad no encuentro como hacer para que una vez que se elimine dicho elemento, aparezca la visualización de los elementos restantes adecuadamente.

```
class Sanwich {
    constructor(id,pan,principal,adicional,precio){
        this.id=parseInt(id)
        this.pan=pan
        this.principal=principal
        this.adicional=adicional
        this.precio=precio
    };  
}
const pedidoUnidades=[];
let panPrice
let principalPrice
let adicionalesPrice
let precioSanwich

//PROCEDIMIENTO 

let nuevoSanwich=prompt("HOLA \n ¿Quieres hacer un pedido? \n\n  1 - SI \n  9 - ESC" );

while (nuevoSanwich!=9) {
    if (nuevoSanwich==1) {
        pedidoUnidades.push(new Sanwich(pedidoUnidades.length+1,infoPan(),infoPrincipal(),infoAdicional(),infoPrecio()));
        
        /*alert("Tu sanwich " + pedidoUnidades[pedidoUnidades.length-1].id + " sera de \n\n" +
        pedidoUnidades[pedidoUnidades.length-1].pan + "\n" +
        pedidoUnidades[pedidoUnidades.length-1].principal + "\n" +
        pedidoUnidades[pedidoUnidades.length-1].adicional + "\n\n" + 
        "precio - $" +pedidoUnidades[pedidoUnidades.length-1].precio )*/
        nuevoSanwich=prompt(resumenPedido()+"TOTAL $ " + total$()+"\n-------\n Quieres  \n\n 1 -  Pedir otro sanwich \n 2 - Eliminar un sanwich \n 3 - PAGAR y enviar pedido \n 9 - ESC" )
    }else if (nuevoSanwich==2){
        borrarSanwich(prompt("Ingresa el numero del Sanwich que quieres eliminar"))
        nuevoSanwich=prompt(pedidoUnidades.length + " Sanwich \n\n"+ resumenPedido() +"\nTOTAL $ " + total$()+"\n-------\n Quieres  \n\n 1 -  Pedir otro sanwich \n 2 - Eliminar un sanwich \n 3 - PAGAR y enviar pedido \n 9 - ESC" )
    }else if (nuevoSanwich==3) {
        agregarPedidoAlDOM()
        alert("Debes pagar tus " + pedidoUnidades.length + " Sanwich \n\n"+ resumenPedido() +"\nTOTAL $ " + total$())
        pedidoUnidades.splice(0,pedidoUnidades.length)
        nuevoSanwich=prompt("HOLA \n ¿Quieres hacer un pedido? \n\n  1 - SI \n  9 - ESC" );
    }else {
        nuevoSanwich=prompt("No comprendimos tu respuesta \n Quieres  \n\n 1 -  Pedir otro sanwich \n 2 - PAGAR \n 9 - ESC" );
    }
};
alert("Adios");

// FUNCIONES

// Estoy intentando armar una funcion de orden superior que me eprmita reemplazar las funciones infoPan infoPrincipal e infoAdicional

function infoPan(){
    let pan = prompt("ingresa el tipo de pan que deseas para tu " + parseInt(pedidoUnidades.length+1) + " sanwich  \n (F) Pan Frances - 10$ \n (H) Pan de Hamburguesa - 12$");  
    let panPrint
                switch (pan) {
                    case "F":
                        panPrint = "Pan Frances 10$"
                        panPrice = 10
                        break;
                    case "H":
                        panPrint = "Pan de Hamburgesa 12$"
                        panPrice = 12
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert("No elegiste un pan valido por defecto se hara con Pan Frances")
                        panPrint = "Pan Frances 10$"
                        panPrice = 10
                        break;
                    }
    return panPrint
}  
function infoPrincipal(){
let principal = prompt ("ingresa cuál quieres que sea el ingrediente principal de tu " + parseInt(pedidoUnidades.length+1) + " sanwich \n (C) Carne - 10$\n (P) Pollo - 12$\n (V) Vegetariano - 11$")
let principalPrint
                switch (principal) {
                    case "C":
                        principalPrint = "Carne 10$"
                        principalPrice = 10
                        break;
                    case "P":
                        principalPrint = "Pollo 12$"
                        principalPrice = 12
                        break;
                    case "V":
                        principalPrint = "Vegetariano 11$"
                        principalPrice = 11
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert("No disponemos de ese ingrediente. Pero lo haremos de Carne ")
                        principalPrint = "Carne 10$"
                        principalPrice = 10
                        break;
                }
    return principalPrint
}  
function infoAdicional(){
let adicionales = prompt ("selecciona un ingrediente adicional para tu " + parseInt(pedidoUnidades.length+1) + " sanwich \n (L) Lechuga - 3$\n (T) Tomate - 4$\n (Q) Queso - 5$")
let adicionalesPrint
                switch (adicionales) {
                    case "L":
                        adicionalesPrint = "Lechuga 3$"
                        adicionalesPrice = 3
                        break;
                    case "T":
                        adicionalesPrint = "Tomate 4$"
                        adicionalesPrice = 4
                        break;
                    case "Q":
                        adicionalesPrint = "Queso 5$"
                        adicionalesPrice = 5
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert("No disponemos de ese ingrediente, pero le pondremos nuestro mejor queso")
                        adicionalesPrint = " Queso 5$"
                        adicionalesPrice = 5
                        break;
                }
    return adicionalesPrint
}
function infoPrecio(){
    precioSanwich=parseFloat(panPrice+principalPrice+adicionalesPrice)
    return precioSanwich
}
function total$(){
    let total = 0
    for (const Sanwich of pedidoUnidades) {
       total=parseFloat(total+Sanwich.precio)
    }
    return total
}
function resumenPedido(){
    let listaResumen=""
    for (const Sanwich of pedidoUnidades) {
        listaResumen= listaResumen+Sanwich.id+" "+Sanwich.pan+"\n   "+Sanwich.principal+"\n   "+Sanwich.adicional+"\n              Subtotal $" +Sanwich.precio+"\n\n"
    }
    return listaResumen
}
function borrarSanwich(sanwichId){
    pedidoUnidades.splice(parseInt(sanwichId-1),1)
}
```

Comment: Recuerda que splice modifica el arreglo original, me he mareado un poco en el codigo, pero quizas debas tener en cuenta esto que te digo, porque si no entonces ese comportamiento "extraño" que tu dices realmente se da por que algunos espacios en memoria desaparecen e intentas luego acceder a ellos por ej, no se, es una posibilidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando muestras la lista de los pedidos actuales en resumenPedido() lo haces mediante el Sandwich.id y cuando borras en borrarSanwich(sanwichId) el splice() lo que hace es borrar a partir de la posicion del elemento que recibes, no con base al Id de tu Sanwich. Es decir que la informacion que muestras no coincide con la forma en la que quieres accessar a tus datos.

o muestras el producto con su posicion actual en el array, o modificas tu funcion borrarSanwich() para que haga una busqueda del producto por id, identifique la posicion y entonces elimine esa posicion. puedes usar findIndex()

```
function borrarSanwich(sanwichId){
    let index = pedidoUnidades.findIndex(x=> x.id == sandwichId);
    if(index > -1)
      pedidoUnidades.splice(parseInt(index),1);
}
```